# Implementing navigation based on mvvm patterm being used Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

My app being developed using mvvm pattern & I am not sure that what pattern I am using?
Some of mvvm pattern are out there like

- mvvm fresh
- mvvm light
- mvvm prizm

to name a few. This is my mvvm class

```
public class AssignmentDetailViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand Button1Command { get; set; }
    public AssignmentDetailViewModel()
    {
        Button1Command = new Command(Button1_click);
    }

    private bool _enableButton1;
    public bool EnableButton1
    {
        get { return _enableButton1; }
        set
        {
            _enableButton1 = value;
            OnPropertChanged();
        }
    }
   //This is for page navigations
    private void Button1_click()
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AssignmentContent());
        EnableButton1 = true;
    }
}
```

How I am using this in xaml

```
<Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  isVisible={Binding EnableButton1} Command="{Binding Button1Command }">
```

According to above pattern being used I want to develop the page navigation. As of now *Navigation* I am doing like `Button1_click()` method above.
Now I want two points to be cleared

1. Which mvvm pattern is this?
2. The way I am using navigation is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: You are confusing patterns with libraries.

Comment: What I know is, those are(above mentioned) mvvm pattern & even few article claim to be the same.

Comment: MvvmLight, Prism or FreshMvvm are not patterns, but libraries. They probably each provide some way to navigate between ViewModels. The pattern you are using is the Command pattern. However, you are tying yourself to Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Dare I say! We have Commands bindings common other mvvm patterns too like fresh mvvm. So this is not any pattern I am using?

Comment: You are simply using MVVM design pattern. The rest are libraries, if you have not included them in your solution,you are not using either of them.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro - I haven't downloaded any yet. The reason is when I google mvvm I found all examples as above only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are learning the Xamarin Forms platform. You are using the existing Xamarin Forms based Navigation. You are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged (to notify changes to your View when your Model changes) in every Models/ViewModels for now. Yourself Binding the Binding Context for all the pages you have! All those libraries you referred to are the Libraries to help you implement the Navigation, MVVM, IOC etc.

You are implementing parts of the features those libraries provides. Then why do you need to think about them? The more bigger your apps become and more works you do manually to manage many of the features they provide - is time consuming. Eventually, you want to use all of those features that some of those libraries provides!

So, using one of those libraries, You will save a lot of time and cost. Commonly all of these MVVM Libraries provides the Features like :

- IOC
- Automatic ViewModel Binding
- ViewModel supports the page events like appearing/disappearing
- ViewModel to ViewModel navigation
- Built in INotifyPropertyChanged in form of BaseViewModel
- Supports multiple navigations like MasterDetail navigation, Tabbed navigation etc.

Confused about the Pattern? Pattern is a COMMON WAY of implementing the System. Every part of the system follows some common rules in term of Names, Accessibility, Implementation etc. Using those libraries, you will follow all/any of the System/Rules/Pattern they offer in form of that Library. All of them Support MVVM which means that, all of your Pages should have their ViewModel. All of your Logics and Data related to that View should Go inside the ViewModel rather than you will Mixup.

It's all your choice whether or not to use those libraries. But, using any of those, you will build the great app that follows the Separation of the parts/concern of the app being developed in cleaner way.